About teens learning to fight off monsters (tv show I think)
I believe one of the actors was Manu Benett from Spartacus, although further inspection it didn't pop up under his IMDb. 
But the guy who I thought was Manu Bennett played a role as a teacher for for fighting and there was this beautiful tree. And there was many leaves on it. But when a leaf fell from the tree it released a monster somewhere the teens had to stop it. 
I thought this movie/TV show was supposed to be aired but I can't find anything. Anyone know the TV show? It was previewing the same time Shadows hunters was airing.

What does the title mean? "Learning to fight monsters," so far so good, but "to show I think," loses me.

It's The Shannara Chronicles

An Elvish tree, known as the Ellcrys, is dying. The bad news is that the tree has been the only piece of magic that protects the Four Lands from the Demon World. Amberle Elessedil is the only one who can save the tree. But she has to unlock magic that the Elves haven't used in thousands of years. With the help of Wil Ohmsford, she travels to find the lost magic. But it won't be an easy task.





(and yes, it was Manu Bennett)
